# How to add z coordinates to the line to make it curve

Tags: java, curve, smoothing

I have inputs height if first coordinate, height of last coordinate, and n where n is a number of points I need to create on the edge including first and last.

I created points that are at equal distance but they form a straight line. I want to have a sinusoidal wave-like curve instead of a straight line. That means points closer to the first coordinate and last coordinates and the rest of the points are gradually increasing.

```
        final double heightOfFirstCoordinate = 0;
        final double heightOfLastCoordinate = 6;
        final int n = 4;
        final double step = (heightOfLastCoordinate - heightOfFirstCoordinate) / (n - 1);
        final List<Double> collect = IntStream.range(0, n)
                                     .mapToObj(i -> heightOfFirstCoordinate + step * I)
                                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As you can see on the screenshot what I produced is the black line but I need to produce the brown line.

[image]

I can't think of any simple algorithm to do this thing without making it much complicated.

Comment: You need the define the direction of the start and end point, then you can apply a simple spline algorithm

Comment: in case the derivative of the start and end point is 0, you can also use a simple sigmoidal function like tanh(x)

Answer (score 0):

assumed the derivative of the start and end points are exactly 0, you can use a cubic function running from 0 to 1 and returning values from 0 to 1:

```
double cubic(double x) 
{
  return 3*x*x-2*x*x*x;
}
```

To transform from the actual coordinates, use

```
y = y0+dy*cubic((x-x0)/dx);
```

where x0,y0 is the starting point the dy,dx are the deltas between start and end points.